# php form not passing variable through?

Tags: php, forms, variables, smarty, validation

Hey guys I am not able to pass the variable "profile" through... This is done with smarty templates btw

```
{if $commentpossible == true}
        <form name="form1" method="get" action="comment.php?profile=5">
          <p>
            <label for="comment"></label>
            <textarea name="comment" id="comment" cols="45" rows="5" ></textarea>
            <br>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="Submit">
          </p>
</form>
        {/if}
```

Basically this page is profile?profile=5 and I want to pass that profile through...I have "5 manaully inputed atm rather than a variable just too see if it would work...it still does not....when submit is hit it just goes to comment.php?comment=&Submit=Submit....(comment is blank intentionally there)...I need to be more comment.php?profile=5comment=blablabla etc etc

Any idea on what could be the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `profile` as a hidden field when you're using the GET method:

```
{if $commentpossible}
        <form name="form1" method="get" action="comment.php">
          <input type="hidden" name="profile" value="5">
          <p>
            <label for="comment"></label>
            <textarea name="comment" id="comment" cols="45" rows="5" ></textarea>
            <br>
            <input type="submit" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="Submit">
          </p>
        </form>
{/if}
```